# VB6 Combo box events

Tags: events, vb6, combobox

I have a form in VB6 with two combo boxes (cboCustomer and cboItemNumber). When someone selects a value from cboCustomer, I want to populate cboItemNumber with a list of item numbers relevent to the customer selected. What event does VB6 offer that I can use? I've tried _Change and _LostFocus and neither are doing what I need. I find it hard to believe that I'm having such a difficult time finding a list of possible events.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the _Click event.  This event fires even if the control is't actually clicked on.  For example, if you tab in to it and use the up/down arrow keys to change the selected item, the click event still fires.

Comment: Yes, that worked. How great it is to learn a new language :-/

Answer (score 3):

As G Mastros says, the _Click event is the one to use, since it fires when the selection is changed via either keyboard or mouse.

If you want to see a list of all the events, then use the Object Browser (F2), and search for or browse to ComboBox. Events are shown with yellow lightning bolts in the Members pane.