# Where is the Visual Basic 6 Combo Box Click Event?

Tags: combobox, vb6, event-handling

I'm new to Visual Basic, I have scoured the net to look for the event handler for the combo box click event but I cannot locate it. I am trying to make an event happens if a certain index is selected with the combo box1 then another combo box2 will populate the selected the index.

i have looked at links like these but it does not explain how or what the person did to access the _ click event [VB6 Combo box events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285359/vb6-combo-box-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code window for the form, select the desired control from the left drop down, then the event you want from the list of all events in the right drop down:

[image]

It will create the procedure for you and make it the active one.  This is the same as VB.NET assuming you have the selectors on.

Comment: OMG ITS RIGHT THERE !!!! THANK YOU PLUTONIX        !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: +1 and you can read about this event in the [VB6 manual topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445415(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using VB6 for ages, but i think what you need is covered here: http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/visual-basic-combo-box-tutorial

I cannot recall having to do anything special when using click events in VB6 at all.

In the first combobox click event, you should be able to have an if statement checking if a certain item is selected using .ListIndex and if so, populate the other.